# Bit flipping attack in hash function for message authentication

Tags: hash, attack, xor, chosen-plaintext-attack, hash-signature

[image: Use of a hash function for message authentication]

In this picture we have a use of a hash function for message authentication.

M is plaintext message. H is hash function. E is encryption block with K symmetric key. || is concatenation of plaintext M with the output of E.

**Is it true that this is vulnerable to bit flipping attack? I'm not sure how though.**

**This is what they said to me:**

> You do the bit flipping on the encrypted hash in such a way that it is
> as you want the hash to be
>
> In a nutshell:
>
> 1. You have plaintext message and the encrypted hash.
> 2. If you xor between the plaintext hash and the encrypted hash you get "X" that if decrypted gives you all bytes to 0
> 3. So to flip the bits you just xor with the correct hash first and then xor with the malicious hash

**But the 2 and 3 are absolutely unclear to me:**

2. Why if I xor between plaintext hash and encrypted hash I get stuff that if decrypted gives 0?
3. What should I xor? Why doing this now the hash will be what I want?

Comment: The attack in the quote assumes E is a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher), e.g. a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) in [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) or  [OFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_(OFB)) mode. Also it names "encrypted hash" the subpart of that stream cipher's ciphertext that's the XOR of the hash and the [keystream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystream), excluding the [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).

Comment: you are right @fgrieu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a counter example could be derived as follows:
Suppose that your encryption scheme is a one-time pad, then you have $E(K, M) = K \oplus M$. In your scheme, the output is $(M, E(K, H(M))) = (M, K \oplus H(M))$. Then, observe that an adversary can authenticate a message $\hat{M} \neq M$ as:

$$(\hat{M}, \underbrace{(K \oplus H(M))}_{\text{original tag}} \oplus H(M) \oplus H(\hat{M})) = (\hat{M}, K \oplus H(\hat{M}))= (\hat{M}, E(K, H(\hat{M})).$$

This is one explanation for steps 2 and 3, and can possibly generalize to other symmetric encryption schemes (beyond one-time pad). For a great exposition of generic authentication techniques, I recommend reading Chapter 9.4 of [Boneh-Shoup](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_5.pdf).